# Django 404 I cannot get Django to redirect 404s to my homepage

Tags: django, nginx, django-views, django-urls, custom-error-pages

I'm having a problem getting handler 404 to redirect to my homepage. Here's what I have and tried...

In settings.py

```
DEBUG=False
```

In views.py

```
class view_404(request, exception=None):
  return render(request, "mysite/index.html")
```

In urls.py

```
From django.conf.urls import handler404

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index')
]

handler404 = "mysite.views.index"
```

I've tried putting the view_404 function directly in the urls.py file, I've tried handler404 = views.index. I've tried handling 404s in my nginx.conf file

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

and

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
location /index.html {
  root path/to/template;
  internal;
}
```

I have not been able to get any of these to work...

Answer (score 0):

Create a view which redirect to your index:

```
def my_404_view(request):
    return redirect("index")
```

And reference to this view in your urls.py file:

```
handler404 = "mysite.views.my_404_view"  # or whatever path you need
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that it it needs to be handled in the projects root urls.py file and it acts globally for all apps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).